# Parse line using regular expressions

Tags: java, regex

```
  String  url =    "http://search.host.com/search-ui/?mq=*%3A*&f=productLine%WS%3A+Globalstar%22%5D&f=product%5B"
```

I want to extract only **search-ui** from the above link using regular expressions. How can I do this in most efficient way. As I can parse the above url using split method. But is there any other way to achieve this.

```
String a[] = url.split("/");
```

So by this way a[3] has search-ui. Is there any other efficient way..

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: when you say efficient you mean fast or accurate?

Comment: then split will be faster than regular expressions

Comment: Without seeing another example to get the requirements. it's hard to say.  Is it the first node of the URL after the .com, the last node before the query stuff, or what???  Currently, `return "agilesearch-ui;` is a correct answer.  :-)

Comment: Your example isn't clear enough. Do you want to extract just the path bit of the URL without the query or just the first section of the path? If it is always "agilesearch-ui" then why do you need to parse. Just make a constant.

Comment: @user949300, yes the first node of the URL after the .com, the last node before the query stuff.

Comment: @gigadot, I am opening a file in which there are lots of url starting with the same pattern. So I have to parse each and every url.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

using `split()`:

```
urlString.split("/")[3];
```

or something more accurate:

```
urlString.split(".com/")[1].split("/?")[0];
```

by the way, it'll be a faster to use a for loop instead of using split but split is quite easier and more readable.

using `regex`:

regexes are more flexible and accurate but slower.

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("^http://.*?/(.*?)/.*?$");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(urlString);
matcher.group(0);
```